Cannot select text that is being displayed in title of tool tip React MUI
In my react app, I have a component which is using the following code:
  <FormControlLabel
    labelPlacement="top"
    control={
      comp?.manualInput ? (
        <TextField
          name="price"
          type="number"
          variant="standard"
          value={comp.price}
          onChange={handleTextValueChange}
          sx={{ width: "150px" }}
        />
      ) : (
        <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
          <TextField
            name="price"
            type="number"
            variant="standard"
            value={comp.price}
            onChange={handleTextValueChange}
            InputProps={{ readOnly: true }}
            sx={{ width: "150px" }}
          />
          <Tooltip
            title={
              comp.access &&
              comp.access.length > 0 ? (
                <Box>
                  {comp.comp.map((acc, index) => (
                    <Box key={index} sx={{ mb: 1 }}>
                      <strong>Type:</strong>
                      <br />
                      Id: {acc.id}
                      <br />
                      Description: {acc.description}
                    </Box>
                  ))}
                </Box>
              ) : (
                "No Type"
              )
            }
            placement="right"
            arrow
          >
            <InfoIcon
              color={
                comp.access &&
                comp.access.length > 0
                  ? "success"
                  : "action"
              }
              fontSize="small"
              style={{
                cursor: "pointer",
                marginTop: "-4rem",
              }}
            />
          </Tooltip>
        </Box>
      )
    }
    label="Price per Part"
  />

Once I hover over the info icon the tool tip opens and the content of the title is displayed inside. However, I am not knowing why I am not able to select the content by just clicking and select the content of the title in tool tip ?
Is MUI affecting the styling ? What am I missing here ? I was using in another file also a tool tip but in the title only contained a string and I didn't use any jsx and it worked I was able to directly select it but in this case I have to use a box with jsx. I don't know if the box and the jsx is affecting anything. I tried using <Box sx = {{ pointerEvents: 'auto' }}> but it didn't do anything

The issue you're encountering with the tooltip from Material-UI (MUI) likely stems from the default behavior of the Tooltip component, which prevents interaction with its content. When you use a complex JSX structure inside the title prop, the content becomes non-interactive by default, making text selection impossible.
To make the tooltip content selectable, you need to modify the Tooltip component's pointerEvents CSS property. This can be done by customizing the Tooltip component using MUI's sx prop or creating a custom styled component.
<Tooltip
  title={
    <Box sx={{ pointerEvents: 'auto' }}>
      {comp.access && comp.access.length > 0 ? (
        <Box>
          {comp.access.map((acc, index) => (
            <Box key={index} sx={{ mb: 1 }}>
              <strong>Type:</strong>
              <br />
              Id: {acc.id}
              <br />
              Description: {acc.description}
            </Box>
          ))}
        </Box>
      ) : (
        "No Type"
      )}
    </Box>
  }
  placement="right"
  arrow
>
  <InfoIcon
    color={comp.access && comp.access.length > 0 ? "success" : "action"}
    fontSize="small"
    style={{ cursor: "pointer", marginTop: "-4rem" }}
  />
</Tooltip>



<Box sx={{ pointerEvents: 'auto' }}>

